# Multicasting in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, multicast

I want to do multicasting in linux for the video/audio/data file transmission.

Is there any utility/tool to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came across [UFTP](http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net) and it fits the bill.

Answer (score 4):

You can use VLC to do this, see http://tldp.org/REF/VideoLAN-Quickstart/x536.html for instance.

Comment: what about (raw) data ?

Answer (score 3):

[omping](https://www.ohloh.net/p/omping) - Use Test IP multicast.